# Adding a dictionary to a list through a function

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have been practicing some coding in Python. I came to a task where I was supposed to add a dictionary to an existing list (which had dictionaries).

The given function (at the end) works, but when I tried to write the following (in the function)

```
    travel_log.append(add_new_country)
```

instead of

```
    travel_log.append(country)
    travel_log.append(visits)
    travel_log.append(cities)
```

and then try to print out travel_log, I would get the following (look at the last dictionary in the list):

```
[{'country': 'France', 'visits': 12, 'cities': ['Paris', 'Lille', 'Dijon']}, {'country': 'Germany', 'visits': 5, 'cities': ['Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Stuttgart']},<function add_new_country at 0x7fefd60e8310>]
```

Can somebody explain why does that happen?

**Full code:**

```
    travel_log = [
    {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 12,
    "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]
    },
    {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 5,
    "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]
    },
    ]


    def add_new_country(country,visits,cities):
    travel_log.append(country)
    travel_log.append(visits)
    travel_log.append(cities)

    add_new_country("Russia", 2, ["Moscow", "Saint Petersburg"])
    print(travel_log)
```

Comment: What is the question about this exactly? Why you see the function at the end? I mean, you appended your function to the list, so you get a function at the end of the list... I'm not sure what is unclear about that part. Also I don't think the function works that you showed, as it will append three items instead of a dictionary.

Comment: You are right, I have not even notice it. Then how do I add a dictionary to a list but through a function? Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference between adding it through a function or not through a function. You create a dictionary (just like you created it inside of your original array literal) and append it. The only difference is that instead of having hardcoded values, you now put the arguments in their place instead. For example: `travel_log.append({'country': country, 'visits': visits, 'cities': cities})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a dictionary and add it to `travel_log` (list),

```
def add_new_country(country,visits,cities):
    d = {'country': country, 'visits': visits, 'cities': cities}
    travel_log.append(d)
```